# All your choice of an employer depends on is whether

Tags: grammaticality

I wonder whether this phrase below is grammatical?

> All your choice of an employer depends on is whether

1) you possess necessary skills and expertise in the sphere of corporate finance. 
2) you love what you do
3) you are ready for overtime work
4) bla-bla

Comment: It's a type of cleft, and it's a good construction. But do you mean *All your choice **should** depend on is ...* ?

Comment: @ Araucaria Do you mean that there is a gap after the word "whether"? I have posted the other parts of this sentence below the first part. No, I mean just "depend" without "should".

Comment: The things on which your choice depends are [the list of these things stated in the form of dependent parts].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's grammatical (I think) but it's awkward.

It's awkward because of the words in between 'your choice' and 'depends on'. And because 'choice' is doing double duty: both 'your choice depends on' and 'your choice of an employer'.

I'd rephrase it as something like:

> When you're choosing an employer, your choice should depend only on whether...
>
> The only thing that counts when choosing an employer is...

Comment: @ AE perfect explanation! If I remove the word "employer" , will the phrase be fine?                                  All your choice depends on is whether...

Comment: Thanks! Sure, if the context makes it clear that you're talking about the choice of an employer, then you can say "All your choice depends on is whether..." - it's still a bit ugly but the meaning is clear.

Comment: I think I will reword it, as you suggested. Thanks.